# non aggregate in group by

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregation

Just would like to know if there is any difference(as in more compute time/performance) in using `sum()`, `min()`, or `max()` in Oracle 11G aggregation query against column for which you just want the value stored.

Example:

```
dt.date_time_key AS Date_Time_Key
a.id AS ID_Key
MIN(start_ts) AS Start_Time
SUM(some_duration) AS Duration
SUM(CASE WHEN blah.blah > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blah_Blah `
```

Why would you use, `min()`,`sum()`, or `max()` for start_ts or some_duration...They all yield the same result for me. which is more efficient or better to use?

Thanks.

Comment: `min()`, `max()`, and `sum()` all yield the same result? Then why you are aggregating them with a formula in the first place. Perhaps just a `SELECT DISTINCT...` would be more appropriate here?

Comment: @JNevill to avoid having them in the group by...I need the first few columns as facts to be grouped by, then need the values of the next 10 columns then need to perform sum case when's on the next 20 columns...

Comment: @JNevill These queries were provided to me and they always used min() for the values of the columns to avoid grouping by them, but now i am seeing they are using sum()...I'm just trying to understand if they're all going to yeild the same result, that being whaever the value is, why use one over the other...

Comment: If there is a small percentage that are in fact aggregating, then you need to choose the correct method of aggregation so you don't get garbage results. If they are yielding the same result regardles off aggregation function used, then they don't need to be aggregated and could be added to the GROUP BY. If you don't want to add them to the GROUP BY because it's work, then your question isn't about which method has better performance, but rather whether you want to optimize for work required or query performance.

Comment: @JNevill very valid point thank you, duly noted...Can you address the question?  When applying an aggregate function to a non aggregate column is there a performance difference in using min(), max() or sum()?

Comment: What have your tests shown you?

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure since I'm certain that it's deeply rooted in the architecture of Oracle, the optimized path for your particular query in your particular system, the size of the result set (Whether any sorting could happen in RAM or is pushed to disk sort) and a number of other things that could influence it. My guess is that if these are truly not being aggregated then `sum()` is probably quicker since there isn't a need to sort the intermediate result set. But... that's a gut. Try it each way and see how your I/O, CPU, EXPLAIN and other measures compare.

Comment: My results are: min(): 50 in 8.693s;  max(): 50 in 8.567s;  sum(): 50 in 10.025s